# What is the output of the following command in bash shell script

Tags: bash, unix

I just have the following cut code and would like to know what is the $DATA_STORE

```
x=`dd if=$FILEPATH bs=2 count=1`
log "---> x = $x"
DATA_STORE=`echo $x | od -c | awk '{print ($2 $3)}'`
log "---> Data_which_stored_is= $DATA_STORE"
```

i have a xml file for check start with :

.

i just want to know what exactly this command do .

Thanks for helping :).

Comment: What research did you do?

Comment: Iam not sure , iam just new for this project ,and i think this will search inside the file first 2 char am i right ?

Comment: Indeed, `$x` will contain the two first bytes of the file `$FILEPATH`. `$DATASTORE` will contain a human readable string representing these two bytes that could be binary.

Comment: `log` is most likely a function defined somewhere in your script, or sourced in. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ugly piece of code using *dd*, *awk* and *od* tries to represent in a human readable way the two first bytes of a file.

You an achieve the same result by using only *od*:

```
DATA_STORE=$(od -c -N2 -An "$FILEPATH")
```

If necessary, you can remove the blanks from the output with some option (I can't remember) or with `| tr -d ' '`.